# Querying for a Date Range

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following data schema:

```
  {
      "Address" : "Test1",
      "City" : "London",
      "Country" : "UK",
      "Currency" : "",
      "Price_History" : {
         "2014-07-04T02:42:58" : [
            {
               "value1" : 98,
               "value2" : 98,
               "value3" : 98
            }
         ],
         "2014-07-04T03:50:50" : [
            {
                "value1" : 91,
               "value2" : 92,
               "value3" : 93
            }
         ]

      },
      "Location" : [
         9.3435,
         52.1014
      ],
      "Postal_code" : "xxx"
   }
```

how could generate a query in mongodb to search for all results between **"2014-07-04T02:42:58"** and **"2014-07-04T03:50:50"** or how could  generate a  query to select only results with values from **91** till **93** **without** to know the date ?

thanks

Comment: Your dates not only effectively strings but are essentially "keys" of the document. This is not a good way to model as "key paths" are fixed. Consider re-modelling or be stuck with JavaScript evaluation, which is much slower by comparison to native methods.

Comment: You would be better off changing your schema so that the price_history is an array and then make the date a field within that with the pricing information of that day, then using the aggregation framework $unwind to produce the results

Comment: unfortunately I don't have any options to change the schema

Comment: Let me put it this way. If you do not change the schema, then you **need** to scan every record in the collection in order to compare the value of the "keys" there as a string and using JavaScipt evaluation. **Every** time you want to query. So do we go and tell the boss the schema needs to be changed or do you want the complaints about why your code performs so badly in a few months time?

Comment: Neil first of all thanks for your comment, could you please post a example (json) how should be design the schema for this particular task

Comment: This is one of the most egregious anti-patterns in MongoDB. I wonder if there is already a name for it. I would call it "dynamic keys", but that 1. sounds too positive and 2. might be confused as a statement against schemalessness in general.

Comment: @Philipp you are very right in your commentary, which would be better with a positive response to "shed some insight". The general case here I think that lacks understanding is "keys as values, is Baad!, Okay". The "dynamic schema" approach should not be "misconstrued" as "do what you want". If this was SQL for example, you would **never** use a "timestamp" value as the name of a "column". Interesting naming choice, but the the real point is **do not do it**.

Comment: every dream has a beginning ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a really good way to model this. A better example would be as follows:

```js
  {
      "Address" : "Test1",
      "City" : "London",
      "Country" : "UK",
      "Currency" : "",
      "Price_History" : [
          { "dateEnrty": 1, "date": ISODate("2014-07-04T02:42:58Z"), "value": 98 },
          { "dateEntry": 2, "date": ISODate("2014-07-04T02:42:58Z"), "value": 98 },
          { "dateEntry": 3, "date": ISODate("2014-07-04T02:42:58Z"), "value": 98 },
          { "dateEntry": 1, "date": ISODate("2014-07-04T03:50:50Z"), "value": 91 },
          { "dateEntry": 2, "date": ISODate("2014-07-04T03:50:50Z"), "value": 92 },
          { "dateEntry": 3, "date": ISODate("2014-07-04T03:50:50Z"), "value": 93 },
      ],
      "Location" : [
         9.3435,
         52.1014
      ],
      "Postal_code" : "xxx"
   }
```

Or something along those lines that does not utilize the path dependency. Your query here would be relatively simple, but also considering that MongodDB searches documents and not arrays for something like this. But you can dissect with the aggregation framework:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Still match first to reduce the possible documents
    { "$match": {
        "Price_History": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "date": { 
                    "$gte": ISODate("2014-07-04T02:42:58Z"),
                    "$lte": ISODate("2014-07-04T03:50:50Z")
                },
                "value": 98
            }
        }
    }},

    // Unwind to "de-normalize"
    { "$unwind": "$Price_History" },

    // Match this time to "filter" the array which is now documents
    { "$match": {
        "Price_History.date": {
            "$gte": ISODate("2014-07-04T02:42:58Z"),
            "$lte": ISODate("2014-07-04T03:50:50Z")
        },
        "Price_Hisotry.value": 98
    }},

    // Now group back each document with the matches
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "Address": { "$first": "$Address" },
        "City": { "$first": "$City" },
        "Country": { "$first": "$Country" },
        "Currency": { "$first": "$Currency" },
        "Price_History": { "$push": "$Price_History" },
        "Location": { "$first": "$Location" },
        "Postal_Code": { "$first": "$Postal_Code" }
    }}
])
```

Or otherwise better off hanging the "normalization" and just go for discrete documents that you can simply process via a standard `.find()`. Must faster and simpler.

```js
  {
      "Address" : "Test1",
      "City" : "London",
      "Country" : "UK",
      "Currency" : "",
      "date": ISODate("2014-07-04T02:42:58Z"),          
      "value": 98
  }
```

Etc. So then just query:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "date": {
       "$gte": ISODate("2014-07-04T02:42:58Z"),
       "$lte": ISODate("2014-07-04T03:50:50Z")
    },
    "value": 98
})
```

I would really go with that as a "de-normalized" *"Price History"* collection as it is much more efficient and basically what the aggregation statement is emulating.

The query you ask for is possible using something that evaluates JavaScript like MongoDB mapReduce, but as I have already said, it **will** need to scan the entire collection without any index assistance, and that is bad.

Take your case to the boss to re-model and earn your bonus now.

Comment: great I will provide your suggestion, btw how does look like the query if I have a i.e { "value.com": 98 } because in this case your suggestion { "Price_Hisotry.value.com": 98 } would not work, or  how does look like the query if I don't know the key "value.com"?. again thx

Comment: @ovntatar A little too broad for a comment without an explicit example. Try the methods here and if you have another question then post one, which I am sure someone will answer.